# Good Free Javascript IDE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, ide

I recently started learning jQuery, so I'm looking for a good free Javascript IDE with jQuery support. If anyone know a good IDE please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need an IDE? I know a lot of people just code with Notepad++ and I like it a lot better personally than Dreamweaver, e.g.

Comment: Search stackoverflow asked a bunch and closed a bunch. :)

Comment: It's not free, but Visual Studio 2008 (with a service pack) and 2010, and 2011 have jQuery and JavaScript support with intellisense.  If you already have Visual Studio then it is free :)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support

Comment: I was using notepad++ but I wanted something with code completion im gonna try komodo edit.

Comment: [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Comment: @DMan It's not a duplicate I was looking for a free one.

Comment: There are free ones in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no JavaScript IDEs that I know of.

There *are* IDEs that support JavaScript, though. Try [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit).

But I personally just use a text editor with good syntax highlighting. When I am on Windows, I use Notepad++.